# Load data permanently in a python file

Tags: python, text-files

I was wondering if it was possible to store in a python file data  from a text file (.txt .dat .csv) and keep it permanently in the .py file. In other term I would like to be able to throw away my text file after the loading not like with genfromtxt.

Comment: no, but you could use pickle, to save the content in a parsed python native format (not text file) and unpickle whenever you need the data.

Comment: Depends what you mean.  You could create, for instance, a list or dict containing your data in the Python file.  For anything more than very small amounts of data, though, this is probably not a great idea.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the advantage of pickle?

Comment: Look up [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).